# Unable to access my boolean list

Tags: java

So I have this List<> which contains boolean arrays:

```
static List<boolean[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And these are the arrays I add into the list:

```
boolean[] myBooleanArray = new boolean[8];
```

So now when I go trough the myList with a for() loop, using this:

myList.get(i);

My output is something like this in console:

```
[Z@65e7c41f
```

But I want to into thoes objects too. How do I do this?

Comment: This question has been asked tons of times here on SO. You have to use `Arrays.toString(myList.get(i))` or use a `for` loop to print each element of the `boolean` array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to print an array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As arrays don't override the methods from the Object class, you get the default String representation which is:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

If you want to print the content of an array, you can use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28boolean%5B%5D%29).

```
for(boolean[] arr: myList){
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

---

I don't know what you're doing with your `List` of boolean arrays, but be aware that you can have small surprises:

```
public class Test {   
    static List<boolean[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean[] arr = {true, false};
        boolean[] arr2 = {true, false};

        myList.add(arr);
        System.out.println(myList.contains(arr2)); //false
    }   
}
```

An alternative is to create a wrapper class that wraps your boolean array and you can use the methods [`Arrays.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28boolean%5B%5D,%20boolean%5B%5D%29), [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28boolean%5B%5D%29) and [`Arrays.hashcode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode%28boolean%5B%5D%29) to implement properly the `equals`, `toString` and `hashCode` methods.

```
class MyBooleanArray {
    private boolean[] arr;

    public MyBooleanArray(boolean[] arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(arr);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MyBooleanArray other = (MyBooleanArray) obj;
        if (!Arrays.equals(arr, other.arr))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyBooleanArray [arr=" + Arrays.toString(arr) + "]";
    }   
}
```

And the main:

```
public class Test {   
    static List<MyBooleanArray> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean[] arr = {true, false};
        boolean[] arr2 = {true, false};
        myList.add(new MyBooleanArray(arr));
        System.out.println(myList.contains(new MyBooleanArray(arr2))); //true
        System.out.println(myList.get(0)); //MyBooleanArray [arr=[true, false]]
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the references by `myList.get(i)`.

To see the difference try this:

```
for(int i=0; i < myList.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(myList.get(i));
    for (int j = 0; j < myList.get(i).length; j++)//+
        System.out.print(myList.get(i)[j]);
}
```

+: I've shown the elements of the array this way to make it more clear for you how you should access the elements of the array.